# React Native Maps with sticky and multiple Callouts - Same as Uber app

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I would like to have multiple callout which are alway open in the same way as Uber taxi app does.

[image: Sample screen]

The criteria I want are

- Multiple Callouts
- Callout can be pressed

I have two solutions. **One** is to always set callouts open by reference once it is mounted, but it comes with only one active callout at once. **Secondly**, I use custom Marker with absolute position and `TouchableOpacity` as child. I can display multiple, but the button nested in `<MapView.Marker>` cannot be pressed.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? If yes please share the code.

Comment: Not at all. I end up using custom Marker

Comment: could you share a sample code showing that custom marker, @Ponleu ? I'm interested in displaying all callouts on load. Your second option could help me achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem for sometime. Actually this is how I stumbled across this question. I wanted to share what I ended up with. Apparently we can place anything inside the Marker component, so putting a View and an Image inside did the trick:

```html
    <Marker coordinate={coords} style={styl.customMarker}>
      <View style={styl.addressBox}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('Click!')}>
          <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styl.addressText}>
            Some location address goes here
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Image source={require('../assets/locationPin.png')} />
    </Marker>
```

```js
    const styl = StyleSheet.create({
      customMarker: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      addressBox: {
        width: 150,
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        paddingVertical: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 7,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        elevation: 3
      },
      addressText: {
        textDecorationLine: 'underline'
      }
    });
```

This is how it looks: [image: Output screenshot]

This is a Grab (Uber alternative) implementation. But you can play around with View and Image styles to achieve Uber like results.

Hope this helps someone in the future. Cheers!

Comment: This approach looks very customizable, but for some reason, my `<TouchableOpacity/>` component does not trigger `onPress()` event. I'm investigating why...

Comment: yeah, that's the issue. button press inside marker is not working. we decided to display the Callout outside map and marker and animate it accordingly.